# How to keep in session XML-based objects?

Tags: asp.net, xmldocument, linq-to-xml

I'm receiving data from web-services in XML and I'm using that data via objects, build upon received XML. So, sometimes I need to store such user-specific objects between requests in session. I know that XMLDocument couldn't be stored explicitly (state server)... so I'm making a terrible construction like:

```
private string _data;
public XmlDocument Data
{
    get
    {
        XmlDocument res = new XmlDocument();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_data))
        {
            res.InnerXml = _data;
            return res;
        }
        return null;
    }
    set { _data = value.InnerXml; }
}
```

So i'm implicitly storing xml... it useful for me during development, because I don't know exactly what properties I need from entire object - I can make simple experimental properties with xpath etc in a pinch...

so it's comfortable fo me, but it looks very inefficient to construct xmldocument from string each time I need to get some data from any property of that class. Is there any way around?) thanks.

Comment: Why can't an XMLDocument be stored in Session explicitly? If it's large, it wouldn't be a good idea, but neither would it be a good idea to store it as a string.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm using state server... so I can't put XMLDocument there.

Yes, it is not efficient way to store... but there are some key benefits for me )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to store data across requests, there's really no getting around serializing and de-serializing the data during each request - with one exception. If you use in-process sessions, it's possible to store any object you want, including XMLDocument objects or even (forgive me for even mentioning this) open file handles and database connections. I wouldn't recommend making your application dependent on in-process sessions though because it will eliminate the possibility of putting the application in a web farm if that ever becomes necessary.

I think your best option is to optimize your current strategy. Are you making sure that the XMLDocument is only reconstructed once during each request? Instead of constructing an XMLDocument, maybe it would be more efficient for you to use an XMLReader, depending on how the XML data is actually used.

Comment: Yes... aybe some optimization ) But XMLReader is not so easy to use ) I prefer easy extractions with xpath or linq ... so I need XMLDocument or XDocument. 

The problem exactly is - XMLDocument now constructs every time I'm getting any property of the class... and I can't store constructed document in the class variable because class will immediately become unserializable )

Comment: If you're using BinaryFormatter or SoapFormatter to serialize the object, then putting the @NonSerialized attribute on a member will prevent .Net from attempting to serialize that member.